# extend boost.asio file i/o for linux

Tags: c++, linux, boost, boost-asio

According to [this question about the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063209/extend-asynchronous-file-io-in-boostasio-to-mac-os-x) there is no asynchronous file io in asio anything but Windows...

So fine, does anyone know of any already written extensions to asio that do asynchronous file io on Linux?

Or does anyone know of any examples on how to extend asio to support asynchronous io to {insert-whatever-here}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that if this was easy to do, they would have done it.

Comment: I understand it may be non-trivial, but I might put in a reasonable amount of work on it if I knew actually how to go about it... So the second question really applies then, are there any examples out there of how to extend Asio. I've read through some of the impl for the serial-port part of the code to get an idea, but it seems to me to be overly abstracted (maybe for a potential windows serial impl addition?)... In any case the code alone has proven... less then optimal.

Comment: @Petriborg: nail on the head.  I've always found the same thing whenever I've looked at extending boost.  Good luck!